# Why does Google Chrome ask me to allow or deny incoming network connection in my Mac? Is that kind of malware?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Whenever I'm browing through some website, Google chrome ( Macbook ) is suddenly showing a popup for confirming whether I trust the incoming connection. Is there any way to know what is causing this popup to be shown? I wanted to remove if there is any malware or some kind of unwanted softwares. Please let me know your valuable feedback.